# simplemodal and gif not loading

Tags: jquery, iis-7, simplemodal

I am using the simplemodal jquery plugin and using it to display an animated gif.  It works fine on localhost, once I move the code/image to the server (IIS 7), the gif will not show up.  Is it an IIS setting I need to change? All other gifs show up fine.  Here is my code that calls the modal:

```
$.modal('<center><img alt="" src="./../../Content/Images/ajaxloader1.gif"/></center>', {      minHeight: 66, minWidth: 100 });
```

Comment: You're missing a period in there... src="./../../Content/Images/ajaxloader1.gif" should be src="../../../Content/Images/ajaxloader1.gif" - is that a typo in your post or accurate from your code?

Comment: No, I changed it and it still doesn't work.  Fiddler shows that it doesn't even load the simplemodal .js file, is this a security thing in IIS?

Comment: That's probably a path thing - IIS doesn't care what .js files you load any more than .css or .html.  Can you show us a little more code and maybe what the paths are to the files in question?